# How to find field lines?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $F(x,y)=x \hat{i}+ y\hat{j}$. Its field lines satisfy
$$\cfrac{dx}{x}=\cfrac{dy}{y}.$$ Then, I write $ydx = xdy$ so that $xy +C_1 = xy +C_2 $ which implies $xy=C$ for some constant $C$. This is how its found in the examples. 
 However, the book says that $\cfrac{dx}{x}=\cfrac{dy}{y} \implies \ln(x)+C_1 = \ln(y)+C_2 \implies \ln(y) = \ln(x) +C \implies y =Dx$.

So, what is the argument that I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: In its original form it is a separable differential equation you just integrate both sides

Comment: What you are missing is the fact that $x$ can be a function of $y$ and the other way around. As mentioned in the previous comment, you need to separate the variables

Comment: Your function is just $F(x,y) = (x,y)$. Let $p(t ) = (p_x(t), p_y(t))$ a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You want to solve $p'(t) = F(p(t))$ and the solution is $p(t) = p(0) e^t$, ie. the straight lines from the origin.